# create a new column, create new data according to the row number R studio

Tags: r

I want to create a new column, name `E`. For row 1-3, I want to change to `1900s`, row 4-6 to `2000s`, row 7-9 to `3000s`. 
like this one:

```
    A  
1   x   
2   x           
3   x           
4   x           
5   x           
6   x           
7   x           
8   x          
9   x
```

change to this:

```
    A  E
1   x  1900s
2   x  1900s
3   x  1900s
4   x  2000s
5   x  2000s
6   x  2000s
7   x  3000s
8   x  3000s
9   x  3000s
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you provided? What exactly is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `rep`

```
df1$E <- rep(c(1900, 2000, 3000), each = 3)
```

Comment: but what if it does not change every 3 rows?like something without regularity: row 1-2 are 1900s, row 3-8 are 2000s and 9 is 3000s.

Comment: In that case `rep(c(1900, 2000, 3000), c(2, 6, 1))`